# Why is this border-bottom-width transition not working properly in IE 11?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

In Chrome and Firefox the transition is smooth but in IE11 the `border-bottom-width` does not transform properly and instead snaps to it's hover state.

```css
.hbtn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0 3px 6px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 3px #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 0;
}

.hbtn.hb-border-bottom-br2 {
  position: relative;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  overflow: visible;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  padding: calc(8px + 2px) calc(20px + 2px);
}

.hbtn.hb-border-bottom-br2:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  border: solid 3px #000000;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hbtn.hb-border-bottom-br2:after {
  transition: all 0.1s 0s linear;
}

.hbtn.hb-border-bottom-br2:hover:after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-width: calc(3px * 2);
  transition: all 0.1s 0s linear;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hbtn hb-border-bottom-br2">Hover Buttons</a>
```

Comment: its happend because the `calc()` in the `border-bottom-width: calc(3px * 2);` just write `6px` instead

Comment: It's calculated from the scss variable in the actual code, hence it's required. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Comment: SCSS is able to evaluate `3px * 2`